# The area of circles tangent inside another circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, area

Consider the following shape:

[image]

Three identical circles are tanged inside a circle.

Which is greater:

1. The area of the shaded regions.
2. Twice the area of the unshaded regions.

**My attempt:** I tried to solve it approximately. Let $R=2$ be the radius of the big circle, and its area is $4\pi$. The diameter of the smaller circles is about $R$ and their radius is $R/2=1$, the area of each small circle is $\pi$. So, the area of the shaded region is $3\pi$. The area of the unshaded region is about $4\pi - 3\pi =\pi$. Twice of it is about $2\pi$ which is smaller than $3\pi$, the area of the shaded region.

However, the correct answer is 2!

Comment: Let use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem

Comment: How can the radius of the big circle be $\;R=2\;$ and the diameter of the smaller circles be "about" (?) $\;R(=2)\;$ ? That'd mean the three circles would intersect at the big circle's center...but they don't.

Comment: Take a peek at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666491/three-circles-within-a-larger-circle . It is even poetic...

Comment: @DonAntonio As I said, I tried to make an approximation!

Comment: @Ahmad Well, that seems like a crude approximation...why not $\;1.5\;$ , too? Or $\;1.7\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio right, I clearly knew that it is less than 2! Do you think $1.7$ leads to the correct answer! I saw the answer which needed prior knowledge, but sometimes we may be able to have good guesses.

Comment: @Ahmad No, I think the correct answer is already written below...yet you have to do some mathematics to reach it. Suppose you mark the big circle's center as M, and then you draw three radiuses from it, one passing over the center of each small circle
. Can you see why the angle between any two of these three radiuses is $\;120^\circ\;$ , or $\;\frac{2\pi}3\; $ radians? Next, some trigonometry: can you deduce from this that each  arc of the little circles between two intersection points with the other two circle is $\;30\cdot2=60^\circ\;$ or $\;\frac\pi3\;$ radians?

Comment: @DonAntonio As I calculated if I used $1.8$ or less I could figure out the correct choice.

Comment: @Ahmad Well, if you can justify why it is $\;1.8\;$ or less then fine...

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry,  I posted my last comment before seeing yours. Yes, I think it is **60** degree because if I connect the center of three circles together I would have an equilateral triangle whose sides passes the insertion point.

Comment: @Ahmad Nice, that's one way of seeing it. Ok, continue on.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Consider the image below:

[image]

Let $R$ be the radius of the big circle and $r$ the radius of the small circles.

If we connect the center of the small circles we get an equilateral triangle with side = $2r$. The center of the triangle is the center of the big circle as well.

The distance between the center of the triangle to the midpoint of one of its sides (aka [apothem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apothem)) is $h/3$, where $h$ is the height of the triangle. In our case, $h = r\sqrt{3}$ (we can easily calculate this with the [pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)).

As we can see in the image, we can now say that $R = r + \frac{2}{3}r\sqrt{3} = r \left(1 + \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\right) \approx 2.1547r$.

$Area_{shaded} = 3\pi r^2 $

$Area_{bigcircle} = \pi R^2 = \pi (2.1547r)^2 \approx 4.6427\pi r^2$

$Area_{unshaded} = Area_{bigcircle} - Area_{shaded} \approx (4.6427 - 3) \pi r^2 \approx 1.6427 \pi r^2 $

Finally, we can check that $2 (Area_{unshaded}) \approx 3.2854 \pi r^2$ **is bigger than** $Area_{shaded} = 3 \pi r^2$

Answer (score 1):

Let $r$ be a radius of the little circle and $R$ be a radius of the big circle.

Thus,
$$\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{2r\sqrt3}{2}+r=R $$
and $$r=(2\sqrt3-3)R.$$
Now, we can see that $$3(2\sqrt3-3)^2<2\left(1-3(2\sqrt3-3)^2\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let the distance between the centers of two small circles be $2\sqrt3$. The radius of the circle circumscribed to the equilateral triangle is thus $2$ and the radius of the large circle $2+\sqrt3$.

Hence, compare

$$3{\sqrt3}^2=9$$ and
$$2\left(\left(2+\sqrt3\right)^2-3{\sqrt3}^2\right)=8\sqrt3-4.$$

We have

$$9+4<8\sqrt3$$

because

$$169<192.$$